# Does SharePoint Server 2016 need a licensed SQL Server 2014?

Tags: 2016, sql, licensing

We're trying to upgrade to SharePoint Server 2016 and I understand that there is no Foundation version for it anymore.

My question is, when I buy the SharePoint Server 2016 Standard/Enterprise license, is there a free SQL server that I can use?

Currently, I have SQL Server 2012. Can I still use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Server 2016 supports SQL-Server 2014 (with SP1), 2016 and 2017. You cannot install it on SQL-Server 2012.

You also need a paid version of SQL-Server (Standard or Enterprise Edition). SQL-Express is not supported as it's limitations are not sufficient to serve a SharePoint environment.

You must also consider the SharePoint User CAL in your price calculation!

**Reference:** [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements)

If your budget and the number of users are limited, you might want to evaluate SharePoint Office 365. SharePoint is included in several plans:
 - [A bunch of "SharePoint-only" plans](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)
 - [Office 365 Business Premium](https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=2). You are limited to a maximum of 300 users here!
 - [Office 365 Enterprise E1, E3 and E5](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans)